# For upgrading to Spark 3.2.1, how to find which versions of other libraries are compatible with Spark 3.2.1

Tags: maven, apache-spark, jackson, dependencies, dependency-management

I am upgrading spark version in my project to 3.2.1 version. I currently have version 3.1.2. How can I check which other libraries need to be updated along with spark. For example I have jetty, jackson etc in my project. For them to be compatible with spark 3.2.1, where can I find which versions of jetty, jackson etc are compatible with spark 3.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use in your project [dependencyConvergence](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) rule of `Maven Enforcer Plugin`.

You will discover if your project use different version of some dependency which is used in another dependency like spark in your case.